# Gradle plugin compatibility - how to find out?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

Can Gradle plugins for 1.11+ be expected to work for 2.+, and if not, how can one find out the state of compatibility?

Specifically, I have had success using Gradle 1.11 in a project spring-boot project. When upgrading to Gradle 2.2, I noticed that the spring-boot plugin does not seem to be available, although I haven't found any references to a particular Gradle version in the Spring Boot Gradle documentation (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html).

Using Gradle 2.2, I get:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'NN'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'spring-boot']
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':webapp'.
      > Extension of type 'SpringBootPluginExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension, DefaultArtifactPub
licationSet_Decorated, ReportingExtension_Decorated, DefaultProjectSourceSet_Decorated, DefaultBinaryContainer_Decorated]
```

Comment: So the verdict seems that there is no way easy way to find plugin compatibility. In this particular case I could actually solve my problem of not being able to use Gradle 2.2 by upgrading Spring Boot to 1.2.0.RC1.

Comment: Boot's plugin is intended to work with recent versions of Gradle 1.x and Gradle 2.x. Which version of Spring Boot were you using before? I've just tried with 1.1.9.RELEASE and Gradle 2.2 and everything seemed ok. If you can let us know where the incompatibility lies we should be able to fix it.

Comment: Ah. Going back to look up what version I was using, where I thought I had used 1.1.6.RELEASE, it seems like I by mistake had boot-gradle-plugin at version 1.0.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the particular plugin, and would ideally be tested/documented there. 1.x to 2.x was a big jump in terms of the Groovy version used by Gradle, which can cause compatibility issues for plugins implemented in Groovy. Also, 1.x plugins using deprecated or internal APIs may not work in 2.x.